Name of old movie about kid given locket off grandma with welsh writing on it?
I don't know how to put this... I watched a movie when I was a kid (and loved it), but can't remember anything about it and would like to revisit it, so would appreciate help. Here are all the details I remember:

I last watched it around 2008/9
The movie was old when I first watched it, not when it came out, but it had to be before 1990.
The movie was in colour
It was an English film and must have been released in the UK.
Literally, the only characters I can remember are the protagonist, who was a young boy, and I think his grandma.
The only plot details I remember is the grandmother gave the boy something for his birthday (a locket I think?) and said item had something written on it in Welsh.
There might have been a female supporting actress in it; however, I'm not sure.
I'm pretty certain it was based on a short story or novella.
I don't think the characters lived in Wales.
The boy and grandmother may have lived in a cottage.
I think I watched it on video, not DVD.

I can't remember much about the film (hence I asked here and not on Google); however, I will try and remember other things about the film, but at the moment this is literally all I can remember. All help is appreciated. 

How do you know the writing was in Welsh?    Welsh uses the Latin alphabet just like English.  Do you remember thinking the writing was in Welsh, being told by another watcher that the writing was in Welsh, hearing a character in the movie say  that the writing was in Welsh, or recognizing Welsh words or syllables in close ups of the writing?

I came to the conclusion that the writing was in Welsh due to 3 things:

I am Welsh, and remember the phrase being something I could understand.
The grandmother says in the film it's in Welsh.
I first watched in in primary school, and my teacher said it was Welsh.

